# Errors when reading column name from csv files and saving as list

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a folder that has over 15,000 csv files. They all have different number of column names.

Most files have its first row as a column name (attribute of data) like this :

```
Name Date Contact Email 
a     b     c       d
a2    b2    c2      d2
```

What I want to do is read first row of all files, store them as a list, and write that list as new csv file.

Here is what I have done so far :

```
import csv
import glob 
list=[]
files=glob.glob('C:/example/*.csv')
for file in files :
    f = open(file)
    a=[file,f.readline()]
    list.append(a)

with open('test.csv', 'w') as testfile:
     csv_writer = csv.writer(testfile)
     for i in list:
         csv_writer.writerow(i)
```

When I try this code, result comes out like this :

```
[('C:/example\\example.csv', 'Name,Date,Contact,Email\n'), ('C:/example\\example2.csv', 'Address,Date,Name\n')]
```

Therefore in a made csv, all attributes of each file go into second column making it look like this (for some reason, there's a empty row between) :
[New CSV file made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FawvB.jpg)

Moreover when going through files, I have encoutered another error :

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 6: illegal multibyte sequence
```

So I included this code in first line but it didn't work saying files are invalid.

```
import codecs
files=glob.glob('C:/example/*.csv') 
fileObj = codecs.open( files, "r", "utf-8" )
```

I read answers on stackflow but I couldn't find one related to my problem. I appreciate your answers.

Comment: First off, you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: If I understand your goal correctly, try replacing `a=[file,f.readline()]` with `a = next(reader)`, and let me know if that works.

Comment: also, you are following good context manager practice with your outfile by using `with ... as ...` but you should also do this with each infile.

Comment: @JasonStein Making a list like this is my goal.`("Filename","Column1","Column2"]`. reader is not defined, is it in different module?

Comment: sorry! did not read carefully enough. since you are already using `csv`, have you checked the documentation for `csv.reader`? it will create a generator that reads one line of a csv at a time. calling `next` will read one line. so my suggestion would be: `for file in files: with open(file, 'r') as infile: reader = csv.reader(infile), headers = next(reader)` (apologies for single line, should be 4). then `headers` will be a list of the headers, and `file` will be the filename as a string.

Comment: posted as answer, so i could properly format code. let me know if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so

```
import csv
import glob 
list=[]
files=glob.glob('C:/example/*.csv')
for file in files :
    f = open(file)
    a=[file,f.readline()]
    list.append(a)
```

here you're opening the file and then creating a list with the column headers as a string(note that means they'll look like "Column1,Column2") and the file name. So [("Filename", "Column1, Column2")]
so you're going to need to split that on the ',' like:

```
for file in files :
    f = open(file)
    a=[file] + f.readline().split(',')
```

Now we have:

```
["filename", ("Column1", "Column2")]
```

So it's still going to print to the file wrong. We need to concatenate the lists.

```
    a=[file] + f.readline().split(',')
```

So we get:

```
 ["filename", "Column1", "Column2"]
```

And you should be closing each file after you open it with `f.close()` or use a context manager inside your loop like:

```
for file in files :
    with open(file) as f:
        a=[file] + f.readline()
        list.append(a)
```

Better solution and how I would write it:

```
import csv
import glob

files = glob.glob('mydir/*.csv')
lst = list()

for file in files:
    with open(file) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        lst.append(next(reader))


try:
    with open(files,'r'.encoding='utf8') as f:
        # do things
except UnicodeError:
    with open(files,'r'.encoding='utf8') as f:
        # do things
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your code adding `with` and `split`. Still, the output is column1 with file name and column2 with all the attributes. I think I explained it wrong because my English isn't really good. What I want to do is [("Filename","Column1","Column2"] so each attributes will make columns in new csv file.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up. I've updated the code. You need to concatenate the two lists. It was still a list within a list within a list.

Comment: With the last code you wrote, I am supposed to add `split(',')` next to `f.readline()` right? Using `+` cause TypeError saying can't convert list to str

Comment: No, it's wrong. I'm sorry, I was just testing it and realized that `file` is not a list.

Comment: So a slight change. Do `a = [file] + f.readline().split(',')` I'm glad I came back to check on my answer. That was a stupid mistake. I don't think it would have been right anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the help! `split(',')` means in `f.readline()` which was a str, you split what's inside by , and makes it into a list of splited str right?

Comment: You suggest closing each file after opening it. But both output seems to have no visual difference. What's the difference ? and output csv file have space between every rows. How can I fix this

Comment: And when there is `','` in a column name like 'NumberOfBacteria(number,ml)' , using `','` as a split makes it into two separate strings. Is there any way I could avoid this?

Comment: @DoHunKim I don't know what you mean by a space between the rows. Can you modify the files that meet that criteria? Are those column names originally in quotes? Like `column1,"NumberOfBacteria(numer,ml)",column2`? If so, you should use the python csvreader which will automatically get the correct column names for you. I've updated my post with the code I would use to do what you're asking.

Comment: Oh thank you! What I meant by space between rows is in every rows filled with file name and column names, there are empty rows.  There were no `'\n'` at the end of each rows.

Comment: Yes it still does with csv.reader. I just need to solve this and unicode problem. I wonder why this is happening.

Comment: I solved spacing problem but do you know how I could fix unicode problem? It seems that it happens to csv with rows that have uneven cells. (first row has 6 cells but next rows have 8,5,so on). Therefore, I want to use `try open` for files with no error and `except open(files,'r'.encoding='utf8')` to othe files.

Comment: @DoHunKim I've updated my answer(at the bottom) with a solution to your problem as I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

a little bit of tidying, proper context managing, and using `csv.reader`:

```
import csv
import glob 
list=[]
files=glob.glob('C:/example/*.csv')
with open('test.csv', 'w') as testfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(testfile)
    for file in files:
        with open(file, 'r') as infile:
            reader = csv.reader(infile)
            headers = next(reader)
            lst = [file] + headers
            writer.writerow(lst)
```

this will write a new csv with one row per infile, each row being `filename, column1, column2, ...`

Comment: Appreciate your help! But there's still a space between every row. Do you know how to fix this? and how can I strip directory from file name?

Comment: not sure about the spaces, but `file = file[file.rfind('\\') + 1:]` will strip the filename to whatever falls after the last backslash

Comment: It works great. Just gotta fix spaces and `UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec `. Thanks again!